# Prove the the intergral is $0$ if $m\neq n$ and $1$ if $m=n$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $$\int_{-1}^1 \cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2m-1)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2n-1)}{2}\right)dx=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         0 & \mbox{if $m \neq n$};\\
        1 & \mbox{if $m =n$}.\end{array} \right. $$

I found the integral of $$\int_{-1}^1 \cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2m-1)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2n-1)}{2}\right)dx$$

and got $$\frac{(m+n-1)\sin\left(\pi(m-n))+(m-n)(\sin\pi(m+n-1)\right)}{\pi(m^2-n^2+n-m)}$$ I checked with maple, this is a correct result.

I can find noway to show this is 1 when $m=n$ because when $m=n$ this whole thing will become $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Hint: are you sure your result is correct when $m=n$? WOLFRAM ALPHA RESULT: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28cos%28x*1%2F2*Pi*%282*n-1%29%29%29%5E2++

Comment: When $m=n$, you are dividing by $0$. When $m\neq n$, you can conclude using $\sin(k\pi)=0$.

Comment: Since that result is not defined when $m=n$, you clearly do *not* have the correct result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigonometric identity:

$$\cos\frac{2m-1}2\pi x\cos\frac{2n-1}2\pi x=\frac12\left[\cos(m+n-1)\pi x+\cos(m-n)\pi x\right]$$

and from here:

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1\cos\frac{2m-1}2\pi x\cos\frac{2n-1}2\pi x\;dx\stackrel{m\neq n}=$$

$$=\frac12\left[\left.\frac1{\pi(m+n-1)}\sin(m+n-1)\pi x+\frac1{\pi(m-n)}\sin((m-n)\pi x)\right]\right|_{-1}^1=0$$

And if $\;m=n\;$ we get again zero for the first integral of cosine above, but for the second one we get:

$$\frac12\int\limits_{-1}^1\cos(0)dx=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{-1}^1 Cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2m-1)}{2}\right)Cos\left(\frac{\pi x(2m-1)}{2}\right)dx
=
\int_{-1}^1 Cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x(2m-1)}{2}\right)dx
$$
is (up to a linear change) a standard integral $\int \cos^2 x dx = (1/2) (x + \sin x \cos x)$

Comment: the second term is $(2n-1)$ not $(2m-1)$

Comment: question was only the case m=n